# Laravel - How to resolve local.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined variable: imgPicture in image upload

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload image using Laravel-8 as the backend.

Request Rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'min:3',
            'max:100',
            Rule::unique('companies', 'name')
        ],
        'website' => [
            'nullable',
            'max:100'
        ],
        'logo'                 => 'nullable',
       ];
 }
```

model:

```
protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'name',
              'website',
              'logo',

          ];
```

Controller:

```
public function registerCompany(StoreCompanyRequest $request)
{
   dd($request->all());

    $arr_company = [
        'name'                              => $request->name,
        'website'                           => $request->website, 
    ];

    if ($request->hasFile('logo'))
    {
          $file      = $request->file('logo');
          $filename  = $file->getClientOriginalName();
          $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $picture   = date('YmdHis').'-'.$filename;
          //move image to public/img folder
          $file->move(public_path('storage/images/company'), $picture);
          $arr_company['logo'] = $picture;
    }

    $newCompany = Company::create($arr_company);
        return $this->success('Company Detail successfully Added.', [
            'newCompany'            => $newCompany,
        ]);
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        Log::error($e);
        return $this->error($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

Every other thing got inserted apart from the logo.

When I dd($request->all()); I got:

> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Since it is a registration form, that doesn't need user login, I only did:

```
const header = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};
```

This only has to do with the image. All other fields got inserted are working fine.

How do I get it resolve?

Thanks

Comment: 'logo'                              => $imgPicture??null, because if image not uploaded then $imgPicture  will be undefined.  or  move  'logo'                              => $imgPicture, to inside  if

Comment: @JohnLobo - I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$imgPicture`  only set if `request` has file or  else it will be `undefined`.

So to solve this issue change like below

```
'logo' => $imgPicture??null,
```

or

```
$arr_company = ['name'=> $request->companyName,];

 if ($request->hasFile('logo'))
        {
              $file      = $request->file('logo');
              $filename  = $file->getClientOriginalName();
              $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
              $picture   = date('YmdHis').'-'.$filename;
              //move image to public/img folder
              $file->move(public_path('storage/images/company'), $picture);
             
          $arr_company['logo']= $picture,
        }
```

Comment: Why is the image not coming to the database. There is image at the front end?

Comment: better add blade file to question .based on your question detail we cant assume whats the issue. and also controller method full code

Comment: The frontend is Angular. All other fields are getting to the DB expect the image. And I can see everything on the console. Do I still send the full code?

Comment: better first check dd($requst->all()); what you get and post that output in question and also show full controller method code

Comment: @midowu also make sure logo is fillable in model

Comment: I have updated the code. logo is fillable.

Comment: @midowu code looks good .look like angular side file is not uploading properly.to verify that try api in postman